# Reason for Python requests.post Being So Slow?

Tags: python, curl, flask-restful

I'm setting up a web api using `flask_restful`

Backend is just bare Flask app with a post method.

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Test(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return {'you sent': request.form}, 201

api.add_resource(Test, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I tried calling this with `requests.post`, but I was surprised at the speed, so I used `curl` which was significantly faster.

```py
import requests
import time
import os

t0 = time.time()
os.popen('curl --data "" http://localhost:5000')
print(time.time() - t0)

t0 = time.time()
response = requests.post('http://localhost:5000', data="")
print(time.time() - t0)
```

Results in an output

```
0.276999950409
2.03600001335
```

My experience in coding web based things is very limited, so maybe there is something obvious that I'm missing here, but why is `requests.post` approx. eight times slower than invoking `curl`?
This api will be the main portal for a suite of desktop applications, so responsiveness is quite important.

Comment: I tried your code in two ways; `debug=True` and `debug=False`. For both, I got `2ms` for `curl` and `6ms` for `post`. That is very different that your result. Are you sure there is nothing else different between these two?

Comment: That's quite a difference, yes. I've tried it on two machines, both just running the code via a vscode powershell terminal. I'm not sure what could be causing such a difference. Any ideas?

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasimazar I also tried from the command prompt with the same result. 
What OS are you running this on? I'm on Windows here...no clue if that makes a difference. 
Also, you really got 2 and 6 ms? As in, it read 0.002 and 0.006?

Comment: One more comment...My original code was actually Python2.7, but needs to be forward compatible, so I left out the `from __future__` stuff in order to de-clutter my code here. I ran the code on Python3.7, and the `curl` is down to 0.06, but the `requests.post` remains >2s.

Comment: I've been trying with python 3 previously, but I tried it with python 2 too. The new result was `97ms` for `curl` and `56ms` for `post`. BTW, I am running the scripts in pycharm and my OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I also tried to change the order of requests in order to remove the probability of caching; but I got the same results.

Comment: I used Postman and managed to find out that it was the DNS lookup that was causing the delay. If I switch the IP to 127.0.0.1 to avoid the lookup the `curl` is 26 ms and `requests.get` is 14 ms. I'll talk to our network admin and be back...